# Using descriptor to access variable instead of binding this variable with the target in the instance

Tags: python

I have just been reading [`momoko` docs](https://github.com/FSX/momoko/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst), and came across the following class:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db
```

Every time we want to access `db` attribute of `base_handler` instance of `BaseHandler`, the `db(self)` will be called, returning `self.application.db`.

What is the advantage of this code over the following?

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = self.application.db
```

This will bind instance variable `db` to `self.application.db`.

I understand that the former approach will avoid us of having `self.db` in each instance. On the other hand, `self.application.db` has extra attribute resolution step (extra `.`).

Are there any advantages of the former approach that I don't see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes `db` read-only. You cannot *set* `base_handler.db`, there is no setter associated with the property:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @property
...     def bar(self): return 'spam'
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
'spam'
>>> foo.bar = 'ham'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You'd need to add a setter for it to be writable:

```
class Foo(object):
    _bar = 'spam'

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value
```

Note the `@name_of_property.setter` decorator; the property object itself gives you a decorator function to create a *new* decorator with the setter replaced with the new decorated function. There is a `.deleter` equivalent as well. See the [`property` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) documentation for more detail.

Comment: Can you show an example of how the property can be made read as well as write? Yes, it is not related to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Martijn, I have just been contemplation on this, and thought up another reason. `self.application.db` may be accessed through descriptor and may dynamically return different `db` objects. As we don't really know the internals of `application` or how it may change in the future, we cannot get `self.application.db` on initialization step and hold it. And should access it through descriptor. Is this logic reasonable?

Comment: That is reasonable, yes. Storting `self.db` would store a static copy, while `self.application.db` might change.

Comment: So, when we use 3d party library, we should account for the fact that attributes may start being accessed through descriptors, and access attributes through descriptors in our code. It's a valuable conclusion. I have never thought of this before.